# Middleman test and console environments for config.rb

Tags: middleman, middleman-4

I'm using Middleman v4 and I'm having issues in both the console and when I use RSpec to unit test my libraries.

Right now I comment out most of my `config.rb` file, something like this.

```
require 'lib/foo'
require 'lib/bar'

#activate external_pipeline ...

#activate stuff
```

Activating features like the external pipeline causes problems in both console and when I'm unit testing. I could use environment variables and conditionals to fix the problem, but I was wondering if anyone has had to approach this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by wrapping all the configuration I don't want to run in RSpec tests or Middleman Console in a conditional statement.

```
#config.rb
...
unless ENV['NO_CONFIG']
  ...
end
```

Then I run my tests with the variable set to avoid the config I don't want.

```
NO_CONFIG=TRUE bundle exec rspec
```

I just feel like it's an ugly solution and I wish there were something more elegant in Middleman.